# Upload file to server with retrofit android?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to upload an image to my server. The image url is `PUT` request with `“Content-Type” : “application/octet-stream”` 
Below is my interface method for retrofit call

```
 @Headers("Content-Type:application/octet-stream")
@PUT
Call<UserIdentity> putUserProfileImage(@Url String url,
                                       @Body RequestBody file);
```

And i am calling it as

```
public void putProfilePic(String url, File profileImage,
                          final Action1<UserIdentity> userIdentityAction) {
    RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), profileImage);

    appCMSUserIdentityRest.putUserProfileImage(url, fileBody).enqueue(new Callback<UserIdentity>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<UserIdentity> call,
                               @NonNull Response<UserIdentity> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                Observable.just(response.body())
                        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty())
                        .subscribe(userIdentityAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<UserIdentity> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Observable.just((UserIdentity) null)
                    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty())
                    .subscribe(userIdentityAction);
        }
    });
}
```

The file contains the image.
Any help?

Comment: I don't understand you're question. What are you trying to do? Is it failing? How? Can you provide logs? BTW I've noticed that you're header has a space missing (not sure if your server is sensitive to this). Instead of `Content-Type:application/octet-stream` it should be `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

Comment: see this post: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server